# django - Filter foreign key in a queryset

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

In the following model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    created_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to do things like this:

> > products = Product.objects.filter(price__gte=Decimal(10)) #It considered all prices I just need the last one

How do i query a product considering only the last price "created_in" related?

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably want `price__price__gte`, as written your query won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

[latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) is what you need:

> Returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name
>   provided as the date field.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(price__gte=Decimal(10)).latest('price__created_in')
```

Comment: So, should I use ...".latest('price__created_in')"? Thanks for reply